# Merging mutiple cell values as criteria of a Sum-if function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In the following Code, I would like to have mutiple cell values as sum-if criteria.

For example, I have two reference cells. One is ID (ex. 522). Another cell is time (ex. FC1 2019). Next, I created one single reference cell from merging two cells  (ex. 522FC1 2019).

[image]

In the code, I defined string variable FC1 and inputted "FC1 2019". How can I include this string variable in the code **Range("C" & g)**, so that the loop every time include this string as value in the criteria?

```
Dim g As Long, FC1 As String
'g is the number of row, i.e. g=4 means 4th row
FC1 = "FC1 2019"
For g = 4 To LastRowGermany + 2
    Range("G" & e).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("BW2019").Range("A:A"), Range("C" & g), Worksheets("BW2019").Range("N:N"))
Next g
' Range("C" & g) means C4, c5 etc..
```

Comment: Haven't you already got it in there?

Comment: It works theoretically, but I am having Problem with adding the text "FC1 2019" to the sum-if Formula within the loop. I do not know the Syntax of adding the a hard text to the sum if Formula within macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what you are asking but I'll take a stab at it.

```
For g = 4 To LastRowGermany + 2
    FC1 = Range("[Column]" & g).Value
    Range("G" & e).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("BW2019").Range("A:A"), _
    Range("C" & g).Value & FC1, Worksheets("BW2019").Range("N:N"))
next g
```

Comment: Exactly, this is the Syntax I was Looking for Range("C" & g).Value & FC1. I did not know how to merge FC1 within this loop. Thank you!